# Understanding cancel() method of Future<T>

Tags: java, multithreading, future

In the documentation of the `Future<T>` interface the method`get()` is described as follows:

> [...]
>
> Throws:
>       `CancellationException` - if the computation was cancelled
>
> [...]

If the computation is in progress and one thread call the method `cancel(false)` on the `Future` object, should all threads that are waiting for the result of the computation throw `CancellationException`? Or the computation will be completed normally and those threads recieve its result?

Comment: How is that documentation unclear?

Comment: @Kayaman So the computation will complete normally?

Comment: That would be the complete opposite of what the documentation says.

Comment: No it will be cancelled. The boolean argument only specifies whether the thread executing the task will be interrupted or not if the task has already started. But the task will definitely be cancelled.

Comment: The parameter is `mayInterruptIfRunning`, the cancellation happens nevertheless.

Comment: I'm totally confused.... So should the exception be thrown or not?

Comment: @Kayaman The thing is I'm implementing my own Future and I need to know what other developers will expect of that class.

Comment: It's quite clear. If the you call `cancel()` then `get()` should throw `CancellationException` (unless the computation has finished already). The boolean parameter may or may not matter in the way you handle the cancellation.

Comment: @Kayaman It's actually clear. But what if I call `get()` and while performing computation call `cancel()`? All threads waiting the result should end up in throwing the `CancellationException`?

Comment: Of course. It's named `CancellationException` for Pete's sake. It's thrown when the `Future` is `cancelled`. If the computation is `cancelled` it can't very well return a result, can it?

Comment: @Kayaman Got that, thank you.

Comment: The interface does allow for leeway, since it doesn't know what kind of computation is happening, if there's something interruptible going on the boolean parameter *may* affect it (it doesn't have to though). The basic contract for `cancel()` is quite well defined however.

Comment: @Kayaman So, if I don't interrupt the thread performing computation (`cancel(true)`), it will be OK too?

Comment: You don't have to interrupt (you may not be able to either), but you do have to cancel it.

Comment: @Kayaman Since [Thread.stop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29) is deprecated, is there any way to cancel computation unless calling [Thread.interrupt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)?

Comment: That depends completely on the computation. Just because `Thread.stop()` is deprecated doesn't mean that it's impossible to stop threads in Java. Simplest example being a thread that's in a `while(keepRunning)` loop.